# How to Implement Multibinding with combox and button?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm learning wpf through mvvm.

I have a Combobox and button. The button is initally disabled on the application loading.

I have two scenarios:

1. The button should be enabled when the items has been selected in comboxbox.
2. The  button should be disabled after the button click.

Here I can able to achieve the 1'st scenario using Converter with respect to the second case I don't know how to implement multibinding for a single component using button and Combobox.

```
 <ComboBox IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="113" Height="19.277" Margin="10,1,-228.962,0" Name="cmbboxFinalstatus">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Finding"></ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="No Finding"></ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Skipped"></ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Skipped Not reviewed"></ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <Button Command="{Binding stop}" Margin="90,1,-228.962,0" Width="62" Height="19.277" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=cmbboxFinalstatus,  Path=SelectedIndex, Converter={StaticResource IndexToBoolConverter}}">End Timer</Button>
```

Converter.Cs:

```
 public class IndexToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if ((int)value >= 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Edit : stop command logic

ViewModel.cs

The stop command will call the below logic

```
 public void stopbutton()
        {
            if (checkdata() == false)
            { MessageBox.Show("fill all fields"); }
            else
            {
                stopWatch.Stop();
                TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
                string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}",
                        ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);
                EndTimerArgument = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
                TotalTimerArgument = elapsedTime;
                IsEnabledSubmit = true;
                IsEnabled = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: So what you want is that when you select something from the Combobox, the button is activated and when you click on the Button it is deactivated? or is there something else?

Comment: Yes as you said the button should activated when i select in combobox and when i click on the button, the button should be deactivated.

Comment: Ok, check my answer, I think that is what you need.

Comment: @HéctorManuelMartínezDurán i don't think you follow the mvvm in your coding solution. I want the solution  using mvvm.

Comment: And the stop command code of the button?

Comment: @HéctorManuelMartínezDurán I have edited the question.

Comment: Tell me one thing, the stop method is called stopbutton or the name stopbutton is just an example? because you can not call the stop command when your method is called stopbutton.

Comment: And one more thing, the first scenario works well and you only need to deactivate the button on stage two, or do you have problems also on stage one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congrats on learning MVVM, it's a good skill to have. I'll be honest though, I'm spotting a few bad habits in your code which you might want to consider getting on top of early. Even if you don't need them right now it's good to start doing things properly because you'll find yourself needing things sooner rather than later.

First of all, I'd recommend creating an enum for your options and populating your ComboBox with data binding. It's only a tiny bit more work but will easily extend to other controls (dynamic menus, TabControl etc) and will give you the ability for two-way binding in future where your view model needs to control which items are selected. In this case you'd create something like this:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(EnumDescriptionTypeConverter))]
public enum MyEnum
{
    [Description("Finding")]
    Finding,

    [Description("No Finding")]
    NoFinding,

    [Description("Skipped")]
    Skipped,

    [Description("Skipped Not Reviewed")]
    SkippedNotReviewed
}
```

Source code for `EnumDescriptionTypeConverter` can be found [here](http://brianlagunas.com/a-better-way-to-data-bind-enums-in-wpf/), you'll need something a bit more robust if you ever want to support multiple languages but it'll do for now.

Back in your main view model you'll need a property for keeping track of the currently selected item and a command handler that gets called when the button is pressed; the handler simply sets the property to null:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private MyEnum? _CurrentItem;
    public MyEnum? CurrentItem
    {
        get { return this._CurrentItem; }
        set
        {
            if (this._CurrentItem != value)
            {
                this._CurrentItem = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.CurrentItem);
            }
        }
    }

    private ICommand _StopCommand;
    public ICommand StopCommand => this._StopCommand ?? (this._StopCommand = new RelayCommand(OnStop));

    private void OnStop()
    {
        // do something with selection here
        this.CurrentItem = null;
    }
```

Your window needs to automatically create a list of all your Enum values so that your ComboBox can bind to it, doing it this way means you can add extra options to your Enum later if you need to and your GUI will update automatically:

```
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="MyEnums" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="vm:MyEnum" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
```

And now finally the XAML for your ComboBox and Button. The ComboBox just needs to bind `ItemsSource` to the `ObjectDataProvider` above and also to the `CurrentItem` property in your view model. The simplest way of controlling your Button's `IsEnabled` state is to add a property in your view model which you maintain yourself and bind `IsEnabled` to that. That would certainly be my own preference because it can then be unit-tested etc but you could also use a converter or simply add a Data Trigger, which is what I'll do here just to show an example:

```
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyEnums}}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Button Content="Press Me" Command="{Binding StopCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentItem}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>   
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

Keep in mind that converters should be avoided because they're really a type of view logic, even if they don't refer to view logic code specifically. I'm not saying don't use them...I certainly use them myself when I need to manipulate GUI objects directly or where it helps make the XAML and/or view model a lot more concise and easy-to-read...just try to resist the temptation to make them your go-to solution for everything because in most cases they're simply not needed.

Comment: Thanks Mark I applied both your Enum based combobox and Data trigger based binding. Both worked like charm. simply you are genius. I learn lot from the post today. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need multiBinding. When you click button, set ComboBox's SelectedIndex to -1, and call Command stop.RaiseCanExecuteEvent().

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you want is to deactivate the Button when you click on it and reactivate it when you select an element of the Combobox.

This is very easy to do. The first thing you have to do is give your button a name, in this case we will call it `EndTimer`, then, you use the `Click` event of the button where when you click on it, its `IsEnabled` property changes from `true` (default value) to `false`.

The `Combobox` has the `SelectionChanged` event, we use it to change the `IsEnabled` property of our `EndTimer` button to `true` again.

XML:

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="113" Height="19.277" Margin="10,1,-228.962,0" Name="cmbboxFinalstatus" SelectedItem="cmbboxFinalstatus_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Finding"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="No Finding"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Skipped"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Skipped Not reviewed"></ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
<Button Name="EndTimer" Content="End Timer" Margin="90,1,-228.962,0" Width="62" Height="19.277" Click="EndTimer_Click"/>
```

Cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace MyWpfApplication
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void EndTimer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            EndTimer.IsEnabled = false;
        }

        private void cmbboxFinalstatus_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            EndTimer.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```